# CSS for TH hyperlink in asp:gridview

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I want to style the anchor links in my gridview header with css. My style for the classes th works but the style for `th` a does not apply to it. It is overwritten by the containing divs a style. Also if I do `th a` or `th a:hover` without a preceding class it does not effect the hyperlinks in my `th`. I have tested this in both IE and Firefox. This is the gridview portion of my css:

```
.gridview  
{  
    border-color: #9BBE00;  
    border-width: thin;  
    border-style: solid;  
    width: 700px;   
}

.gridview th  
{  
    background-color: #F4A80A; 
    color: White;  
    font-weight: bold;  
}  
.gridview th a  
{  
    font-weight: bold;  
    color:Red;  
}  
.gridview th a:hover  
{  
    font-weight: bold;  
    color:Red;  
}  
.gridview td  
{  
    text-align:center;  
}
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of the HTML output? Are you aware that you're not applying any new or changed rules on `:hover`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a specificity issue. CSS rules are weighted not only by their source and order, but according to a formula:

1. Inline? 1000 points
2. IDs in selector? 100 points for each
3. Classes and pseudo-classes? 10 points each
4. Specific elements? 1 point each

Therefore you might have something like this:

```
div#something a { color: blue; } /* 102 points */
```

overriding your style:

```
.gridview th a { color: red; } /* 12 points */
```

You can solve this by either making your style more specific:

```
div#something .gridview th a { color: red; } /* 123 points */
```

or using the hackier `!important` approach:

```
.gridview th a { color: red !important; } /* overrides more specific selectors */
```

To be technically correct, I should mention that this is not really straight addition of points if any position reaches 10. For example, if for some strange reason you had a selector with 12 classes, the specificity weight might be:

```
0   1   12   0
```

That is, don't carry the one. The above is less specific than:

```
0   2   0   0
```

Finally, I assume you realize your `:hover` style is the same as your plain link style.

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with the way the GridView control renders table HTML. The header row is not contained in the thead element as expected.

**Correctly using thead and th**

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Column One Header
                </th>
                <th>
                    Column Two Header
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Column One
                </td>
                <td>
                    Column Two
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**GridView Header**

The grid view control instead renders the header cells inside the table body using td instead of th.

```
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Column One Header
                </td>
                <td>
                    Column Two Header
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Column One
                </td>
                <td>
                    Column Two
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

You can add a CSS class to be appended to the GridViews header like so.

```
 <style type="text/css"> 
    .gridview td.gridviewheader
    {  
        background-color: #F4A80A; 
        color: White;  
        font-weight: bold;  
    }  
    .gridview td.gridviewheader a  
    {  
        font-weight: bold;  
        color:Red;  
    }  
    .gridview td.gridviewheader a:hover  
    {  
        font-weight: bold;  
        color:Red;  
    }  
    </style>

    ....

    <asp:GridView ID="gvExample" CssClass="gridview" runat="server">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridviewheader" />
        <Columns>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Good luck, hope it helps.